# Difference between setting an HTML attribute to "", null and undefined using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a difference between the following three lines of code?

- `htmlElement.style = "";`
- `htmlElement.style = null;`
- `htmlElement.style = undefined;`

Because to me it seems like they do exactly the same thing.
It always sets the attribute to an empty string, even if you would expect it to remove the attribute completely (in case of setting it to null/undefined).

In this demo you can see, that it adds the attribute `style=""` in all three cases:

```html
<input><button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.style = undefined; this.previousElementSibling.value = this.previousElementSibling.outerHTML;"> Set style to undefined </button><br>
<input><button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.style = null; this.previousElementSibling.value = this.previousElementSibling.outerHTML;"> Set style to null </button><br>
<input><button onclick="this.previousElementSibling.style = ''; this.previousElementSibling.value = this.previousElementSibling.outerHTML;"> Set style to empty string </button>
```

This behaviour seems to be the same with every HTML attribute. I also don't see a difference when removing properties from an attribute:

- `htmlElement.style.display = "";`
- `htmlElement.style.display = null;`
- `htmlElement.style.display = undefined;`

In which case it always completely removes the properties from the attribute.

So is there any difference between setting an HTML attribute or property of an attribute to `""`, `null` or `undefined`?

If there is not, why is there no difference and which is the prefered way of deleting an attribute or a property of an attribute?

Comment: If you actually wanted to remove the `style` attribute from the element you would use [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute). So for your example snippet `this.previousElementSibling.style.removeAttribute('style');`

Comment: Each element is given all of it's attributes by the browser. You can't completely remove those. All you do it just tell the browser to set it to its default value again. Just try `const html = document.createElement("div"); console.log(html);`. You'll see a huge list of all the data attached to the element by the browser. The "preferred" way of deleting attributes is to use [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute). But that too will just "reset" it to the browser default.

Comment: @pilchard Good to know, thank you. And which is the prefered way to remove a property of an attribute? (for example to remove the display property from the style attribute)?

Comment: If you're only removing one style rule then you can use [`Element.style.removeProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty) ie. `this.previousElementSibling.style.removeProperty('background')` If you want to remove all inline styles use `Element.removeAttribute('style')`

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know there is a function for removing a single property. Thanks. So i guess the three ways i listed/use are not really common? Do they have some downsides?

Comment: The ways you listed are very common and of the three the most appropriate is the empty string `''` since HTML attributes are necessarily strings. Setting it to either `undefined` or `null` may have unexpected results (as noted in the documentation for `removeAttribute`)